# XMAPP, Xibo Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException

Tags: http, xampp, http-status-code-404, slim

I am trying to install Xibo CMS 4.0.4  on xampp (windows) and I get the following error:

[Slim\Exception\HttpNotFoundException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmPLK.png)

I have  check some [posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmPLK.png) with the same topic here and non of the given solutions I could use to fix the issue, since I cannot find **$app = AppFactory::create();** in my any of the files!

Is it possible that I am usig a wrong software package? I downloaded it from this link https://xibosignage.com/downloads .
[Xibo CMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNmh4.png)

Comment: Have you tried to ask the Xibo support? I guess you need to configure the Xibo basePath correctly. `$app->setBasePath($container->get('basePath'));`

Comment: Hi, No I havent contact Xibo support, I tired this change, but it didnt work  '$basePath = str_replace('/xibo/web/install', '', $app->getBasePath());'

Comment: Try to use the PHP internal webserver instead. This command should work: `php -S localhost:8000 -t web/`. Then open `http://localhost:8000`

Comment: I tried path localhost/xibo/web/install/index.php/1 and then proceeded